# How to get Github repo locations of all gems in Gemfiles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I have a Gemfile with a list of gems, ie:

```
gem 'celluloid'
gem 'typhoeus'
```

Is there anyway to get a list of the Github repo urls for all of these Gems at once without me looking them up manually? Perhaps using bundle?

IE, I want to get this returned:

```
https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid
https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gem might not *have* a public github repo... It could be a private repo, or stored on a different host, or even not online at all. So there is no guarantee that you'll be able to map each gem to a github repo.

However, there are a few tings you could try to figure it out, such as:

- First, find the gemspec. It could either be local (`gem spec <name>`) or remote (`gem spec -r <name>`).
- Parse the above YAML.
- Check each gemspec homepage.
- Check each gemspec description.
- If the above fails, try searching github directly - e.g. with [`Octokit`](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb).
- Handle special edge cases, such as `ActionCable` being within the `rails` repository.

This is clearly a non-trivial task... Thankfully however, this library already handles lots of the hard work:

https://github.com/teeparham/gemdiff

Usage:

```
> gem install gemdiff

> gemdiff find celluloid
> https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid

> gemdiff find typhoeus
> https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus

> gemdiff find notarealgem12321
> ERROR:  No gem matching 'notarealgem12321 (>= 0)' found
> Could not find github repository for notarealgem12321
```